# MySQL searching text taking into account small errors

Tags: mysql, search

Is any function in mysql to search text which is not exactly the same as in database (and get me percent of matching ? )
Example:
Word in database:

```
Id | name 
1  | television
2  | computer 
3  | window
```

If I type: teleision I want to  find television
If I type: komputr  I want to  find  computer 
If I type: windows  I want to  find  window

Answer (score 0):

I would build a database of common misspellings from a massive datasource like Wikipedia. If a direct hit is not found, then search the misspellings table. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings

Also, there are ways of computing distance - see http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/24/1000x-faster-spelling-correction-source-code-released/ for spelling correction open source code.